# FLUTTER BUILD ERROR Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, location, google-play-services

i have a flutter project with location library, but there was an error like this :

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :location
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
```

> and this library location version :
> `location: any`

> this is my gradle.build :

```
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Did you find any solution

Comment: not yet, but i was change library from service location to geolocator.

Comment: I solved it by downloading location package locally and updated the version code

Comment: can you send link for download location package?

Comment: it is available in pub.dev right side, --- https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation

Answer (score 0):

turn off wifi, and run again. i had same issue a week ago and no solution yet

Comment: i dont think so, always have problem with this library.
and i change library to geolocator and all fixed